# SQL: How are min and max of Integer-types calculated?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

Can any one tell me how the range of the data types are calculated? For example, in MySQL or PostgreSQL where we have smallint, integer and bigint, the range of smallint is from -32768 or +32767. How are these ranges calculated?

Comment: By using … ahm, _Math_ …?

Comment: I'm asking how the value -32786 and +32767 is derived?

Comment: They result out of the fact that computers use the binary system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data type is `int` which is represented as 2-bytes type. `2 bytes` means `2 x 8 = 16` bits in it's binary representation. Also, your sample data type is *signed* - and that means highest bit will be used as sign (`0` for positives, `1` for negatives).

From math it's known that with binary values you can hold `2^n` unique values, i.e. for your `16-1` bits that will be 15 free bits. So that will be `-(2^n) .. 2^n-1` range, where `n=15`. When you'll calculate `-(2^15)` and `2^15 - 1` you'll get your `-32768` and `32767`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Look to this pages in documentation

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html

Numbers are based from data binary width 0111111111111111 ~ 32767, 1000000000000000 ~ -32768

you can find lot of documentation: search "complement format arithmetic numbers"